# External API handling errors with php and echo to user

Tags: php, api, error-handling

I am working with my first external API where you put the vehicle registration in a form and press the submit button and all the vehicle data is returned, everything that side is working correctly and I have no issues with that.

```
    $registration= $_GET['registration'];
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://uat.driver-vehicle-licensing.api.gov.uk/vehicle-enquiry/v1/vehicles",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
 CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode(['registrationNumber' => $registration]),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "x-api-key: myapikey",
    "Content-Type: application/json"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);


$decoded=json_decode($response,true);
```

What I am struggling with is handling the errors, I have tried numerous ways but just cant get my head around it.

In the API docs it gives this example

```
           {
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": 400,
      "code": "ENQ103",
      "title": "Bad Request",
      "detail": "Invalid format for field - vehicle registration number"
    }
  ]
}
```

The API docs also gives you 'test' registration plates that will give different errors, the registration I am using is supposed to throw a 400 but if I do:-

```
$err=$decoded['errors'];

var_dump($err);

Output is:- 

Undefined index:
```

So my question is, how do I handle the errors so I can alert the end user with the status and detail?

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Probably not the cause of your issue but please don't manually create JSON strings, especially with variable content. Use the tools provided... `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode(['registrationNumber' => $registration]),`

Comment: Are you sure there's a specific number to use that responds with a 400? Typically, a 400 response means there's something incorrect about the request payload. It's not usually used to represent a data problem. What's an example of this registration number? Can you link to the API docs?

Comment: https://developer-portal.driver-vehicle-licensing.api.gov.uk/apis/vehicle-enquiry-service/mock-responses.html#error-responses

Comment: Are you making requests to the [test environment](https://developer-portal.driver-vehicle-licensing.api.gov.uk/apis/vehicle-enquiry-service/vehicle-enquiry-service-description.html#test-environment) (note the URL is different)? Have you checked the value of `$_GET['registration']` to make sure it is actually `ER19BAD`?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your responses, couple of things, I have changed the code like you said but  do I still use json_decode so I can echo out the data in my form fields because if I write "echo $response['registrationNumber'] it give an error, and also now when I do a var dump it throws an error of undefiend index 'errors'

Comment: Yes, you still need to decode the response as JSON if you intend on using it as a data structure. If you've changed your code, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69443178/edit) to match. Please also show the actual URL you're using

Comment: Thank you I have change my code accordingly,

Comment: Phil, I have just read the docs again and they didnt send me a test api key just production one so I cannot use that address and probably why I am getting errors now